# Use a variable throughout a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

I am trying to implement a socket.io messaging system in a vue component. I keep declaring a variable assigned to the value `require('socket.io-client')`.

How do i make it so i only declare this variable once and then use the one instance throughout the vue component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the script tag you can import socket-io.client as follows;

```html
<script>
import io from 'socket.io-client';
...
```

After import you can declare a variable inside data called socket by creating an instance of io

```js
export default {
   data() {
     return {
       socket: io("Your socket url")
...
```

You can use socket variable lets say in the **created()** lifecycle method like this for example;

```js
created() {
   this.socket.emit('LOGIN');
   this.socket.on('CREATED', data => {
      console.log(data);
   });
...
```